# Swift: How can I have a listener that reports when connection is lost and when it comes back?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2, reachability

I would like to call a method when my iOS app starts, but I just want to call this method when there is connection. I have found that in Objective-C you can use `Reachable`, but it turns out that this method is not part of Swift.

I have found a pod called [Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift), and I am using the example that was provided:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let reachability: Reachability
    do {
        reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to create Reachability")
        return
    }
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "reachabilityChanged:",
        name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,
        object: reachability)

    do {
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        print("This is not working.")
            return
    }
}

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.isReachable() {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    } else {
        print("Not reachable")
    }
}
```

However, this is not properly working. I works only when the I enter that ViewController, but not when I turn on and turn off the WiFi.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solve this issue by declaring `reachability` as an instance variable of the ViewController:

```
var reachability: Reachability!
```

So this variable should be removed from the method `viewWillAppear`.

**Swift 2**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    do {
        reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to create Reachability")
        return
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "reachabilityChanged:",
        name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,
        object: reachability)

    do {
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        print("This is not working.")
        return
    }

}

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.isReachable() {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    } else {
        print("Not reachable")
    }
}
```

**Swift 3** (provided by [Burning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7110268/burning))

```
var reachability: Reachability!
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    reachability = Reachability()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)

    do {
        try reachability?.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        print("This is not working.")
        return
    }

}

func reachabilityChanged(_ note: NSNotification) {

    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.connection != .none {
        if reachability.connection == .wifi {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    } else {
        print("Not reachable")
    }
}
```

This worked properly :).

Comment: Hey I tried to use this for my project, but it seems that in swift 3 .reachabilityForInternetConnection() is not recognised: can you help me how to fix it?